# Big O notation of simple anagram function

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

I've worked up the following code which finds anagrams. I had thought the big O notation for this was `O(n)` But was informed by my instructor that I am incorrect. I am confused on why this is not correct however, would anyone be able to offer any advice?

```
# Define an anagram.
def anagram(s1, s2):
    return sorted(s1) == sorted(s2)

# Main function.
def Question1(t, s):
    # use built in any function to check any anagram of t is substring of s
    return any(anagram(s[i: i+len(t)], t)
                 for i in range(len(s)-len(t)+ 1))
```

Function Call:

```
# Simple test case.
print Question1("app", "paple")
# True
```

Comment: You can't ignore the cost of `anagram` when assessing the cost of `Question1`

Comment: Can you provide how function called? From what it looks now complexity is `len(s)-len(t)+ 1`, but I am not sure what it suppose to do in this case. It doesn't looks a like something that suppose to work correctly.

Comment: I did not mean to ignore the cost of `anagram`. Given that Big O notations require simplification I thought I had simplified it to the correct formula, I guess I simplified incorrectly. I have also added the function call to the original question

Comment: The multiple calls to `anagram` sort `t` repeatedly (which is quite inefficient), and sorting it once is already `O(klog(k))` -  (where `k = len(t)`) how could the overall complexity possibly be `O(n)`? (if `n = len(t) + len(s)`)

Comment: It's not like you can simplify stuff at random... `Question1` iterates `len(s) - len(t) + 1` times and each iteration  is `O(len(t) × log(len(t)))` due to the call to `sorted`. How you decided that this is O(n) (where n is what?) is anybody's guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> any anagram of t is substring of s

That's not what your code says.

You have "any substring of s is an anagram of t", which might be equivalent, but it's easier to understand that way.

---

As for complexity, you need to define what you're calling N... Is it `len(s)-len(t)+ 1`?

The function `any()` has complexity N, in that case, yes.

However, you've additionally called `anagram` over an input of T length, and you seem to have ignored that.

`anagram` calls `sorted` twice. Each call to `sorted` is closer to  `O(T * log(T))` itself assuming merge sort. You're also performing a list slice, so it could be slightly higher.

Let's say your complexity is somewhere on the order of `(S-T) * 2 * (T * log(T))` where T and S are lengths of strings.

The answer depends on which string of your input is larger.

Best case is that they are the same length because then your range only has one element.

Big O notation is worst case, though, so you need to figure out which conditions generate the most complexity in terms of total operations. For example, what if T > S? Then `len(s)-len(t)+ 1` will be non positive, so does the code run more or less than equal length strings? And what about S < T or S = 0?

Answer (score 1):

This is not N complexity  due a few factors. First one [sorted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) has O(n log n) complexity. And Potentially you can call it few times (and sort T and S), if T long enough.